# Magento not sending order confirmation emails to admin

Tags: orders, email, cron, ce-1.9.2.0, order-confirmation

I'm at loss on what to do.

This morning I configured cron and according to Aoe_Scheduler the emails in the queue are sent each 5 minutes. I don't, however, receive new order confirmations on my email account. I've triple checked whether I've configured the right confirmation address and I quadruple checked spam folders, but no emails there.

I'm worried that the customers didn't get any emails either. Does anyone recognize this problem? I ran 1.9.1 (and since a few minutes 1.9.2).

edit: Creating an account or requesting a new password on frontend does sent emails.

Comment: What do your outbound mail logs show?

Comment: @BenLessani-Sonassi I'm on a shared magento server so I can't access those logs directly ( I'll contact my hostingprovider) Thanks for the log suggestion.

Comment: Also setting  Aoe_Scheduler `Queue configuration -> Queue Usage -> Never ` helps.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try a workarround:

in CMS > SALES EMAILS
Set Order > Sent Emails via seperate Mail (BCC is Buggy)

Magento know this bug and will fix in 2.0.

Comment: When is fix scheduled for?  Is it fixed now?

Answer (score 9):

Three days were spent investigating and addressing those hiccups, and I can now share my newly found knowledge of the possible problems arising from updating Magento to 1.9.

First of all, Magento 1.9+ relies completely on cron jobs to send transactional emails. If you didn’t have cron jobs set up properly before, you are going to have to do it now.

First of all make sure you have set up cron tasks in the Magento admin under `System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Cron`. The default settings are:

```
Generate Schedules Every: 15
Schedule Ahead for: 20
Missed if Not Run Within: 15
History Cleanup Every: 10
Success History Lifetime: 60
Failure History Lifetime: 600
```

There are people suggesting these settings should be changed, but since they can’t seem to agree on the best combination, I’d rather leave it as it is.

You then need to go into your hosting control panel and set up cron jobs. In cPanel it’s under Advanced > Cron Jobs. Set them up to run every five minutes and use this command:

```
php -f /home/username/public_html/cron.php
```

Check that the above path is correct and that the file cron.php is actually there in the root of your Magento installation (if you’ve just upgraded, it should be). Change username to the correct account.

Now, I initially made the mistake of following the advice of the developers at xtento.com who say to use a wget command string:
`wget -O /dev/null -q http://www.YOURDOMAIN.com/PATH_TO_MAGENTO/cron.php`.

This did not work for me at all, whereas the php command did, so my advice is: stick with that.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your php suggestion of "php -f /home/username/public_html/cron.php" worked for me.

Comment: Awesome man! it worked for me too, like a charm

Comment: Using wget should work as well.. I'm curious as to what went wrong there

Comment: Thanks, I was not running cron on the DEV instance and noted that forgot password emails were sending but order confirmation not following upgrade to 1.9.4.1... Adding the cron for the DEV site resolved the order email sending. Appears Transactional Emails are sent via cron as of 1.9. The following is the syntax we use for our cron, can be helpful to stop the cron triggering db updates mid upgrade: "! test -e /absolute/path/to/your/sites/document/root/maintenance.flag && php -f /absolute/path/to/your/sites/document/root/cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1"

Answer (score 2):

Order confirmation emails were not sending to customer or us. Checked cron jobs under cpanel and it was empty. My test site worked fine so checked cron jobs to find this setting and instantly 60 emails came in once I set it in live site. Hope this helps someone, drove me crazy.

min: 0,26,42,58 hour:* Day:* Month:* Weekday:*

Command: `php /home/username/public_html/cron.php > /dev/null`