# Magento 1.9 - Order copy email not send, order update is OK

Tags: magento-1.9

Using magento 1.9 and when I use the send order email copy method BCC it does not send the order email to the bcc adres, the customer does get the email.

When I do the same for order update it works fine.

I am not using the email queue, that's disabled with aschroder smtp.

Answer (score 0):

In System > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails > Order >Set Send Order Email Copy Method to seperate Mail

Refer [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73510/magento-not-sending-order-confirmation-emails-to-admin)

Comment: Doesn't help. Also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, somebody changed it on storelevel :-( Fixed